# how to avoid delay playing wav file in JS

Tags: javascript

I have programmed my site so that a sound plays when the user clicks on an image. I did this with JS. But there is a problem. There is a long delay of about 5 seconds before the sound plays that is after you click on the image. What can I do to make the sound play without delay? The sound is a wav file.

Comment: Is the delay the time taken for the browser to download the wav file? Show your code...

Comment: Let me ask a counter-question: how can we know without seeing the code?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. Where do I paste my code?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to pre-load the sound file. This will download the file without playing it so that it is available when you want to play it.

You can do this with an embed element:

```
<embed name="mySound" src="sound.wav" loop="false" autostart="false" hidden="true">
```

Or by making an AJAX request, so the file is cached by the browser, for example using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({ url: "sound.wav" });
```

Comment: This is the code that I have for playing the sound. IT is similar to the code that you suggested above. The reason for my code was that it was only palying the sound only once. When the user clicks again nothing happens. So what do I do? function playSound(color) {
   
    $("#wavLoader").html("<embed src='/sounds/" + color + ".wav' hidden=true starttime='00:00'autostart=true loop=false>");
     
    }